# Observing mempool firsthand with only an execution client

Tags: go-ethereum, txpool, eth-2.0, clients

My goal: Saving all pending transactions that are gossiped around to a database

I'd prefer running a modified execution client without a consensus client, that saves all pending transactions to a time series database.

[This question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/148559/run-execution-client-without-consensus-client) suggests, that you can't run an execution client without a consensus client, because the consensus client is needed to sync the node.

As far as I understand it, syncing my node wouldn't be necessary and using only an execution client would be enough for my use-case. Or am I missing something?